# Going from a Canadian Master's to an American PhD? [CS]

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, canada

This was inspired by another question [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/177415/do-us-phd-programs-prefer-applicants-without-a-masters-degree).

In Canada (and Europe as I believe), the graduate school process is a little different than in the US. The default here for people going into academia/research is to do a thesis-based Master's (1-2 years) followed by a PhD (4-5 years). The Master's is basically the first two years of an American PhD (according to Canadian professors I talked to), except that it culminates in a thesis.

Of course in the US, the default is to directly enter a PhD after undergrad (this is rare within Canada).

Question: After I graduate from a Canadian thesis-based Master's, what are the prospects of me doing a PhD in America? How do committees evaluate such candidates? Would the connotations of having done a US Master's and then applying to a PhD hold here (as in the question linked above)? Once admitted, would I be treated differently than direct-to-PhD students?

My field is theoretical computer science FWIW.

Comment: You can probably be guided by the following as well as other answers there: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/177418/75368

Comment: @Buffy yes I've seen this (linked in my question). The answer is about US Masters and a lot of the points don't apply to Canadian ones. I'm wondering if due to the country differences, someone with a Canadian Masters is treated differently by a committee than someone with an American Masters, and to what extent.

Comment: Again, the same applies. Don't fret.